# Real analysis and Dirichlet function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be Dirichlet function:$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x\in\Bbb Q$} \\
0, & \text{if $x\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$}
\end{cases}$$and let$$f_{m,n}(x)=\cos^{2n}(2\pi xm!)$$a) prove that $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{m,n}(x)=f(x)$$b) does there exist a set of continuous functions $\{f_n\}$ on $\Bbb R$ such that$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$$for any $x\in\Bbb R$?

The part a has a simple proof, since for quotient $x$ we have an $m$ such that $2xm!$ is an even integer and $\cos^{2n}(2\pi xm!)$ would be $1$ from a moment on. The same proof for $x\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ holds. But i am stuck in the 2nd part. Any idea would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about $f_n(x)=\cos^{2n}(2\pi x n!)$?

Comment: I mentioned it but it was wrong. Actually as a hint my professor said there doesn't exist such a set of functions but I don't know how to proceed to a rigorous proof........

Comment: If my memory is correct, (b) requires Baire Category argument.

Comment: Would you plz elaborate on it?

Answer (score 1):

[Baire's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) implies that if the $f_n$ are continuous and $$\forall x \in \Bbb R,\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$$

Then the set of all points where $f$ is continuous is dense in $\Bbb R$.

**Hint.**

Define $o(x)$ to be the oscillation of $f$ at $x$, and prove that the continuity set of $f$ is the intersection of the (countably many, open dense) sets $$C_n=\{x\in\Bbb R: o(x)<\frac{1}{n}\}$$